# Neo4j Virtual machine in windows azure

Tags: javascript, azure, neo4j

I have created a Neo4j virtual machine on windows azure using VM Depot.My Virtual machine size is' A1 (1 core, 1.75 GB memory)'. But while accessing from web browser I always get an error 'Disconnected from Neo4j' like given below with very poor Performance.How to improve the performance?I used to access it via azure website.

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to share you log files from the neo4j store? data/graph.db/messages.log and data/log/* perhaps via dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is Memory, Neo4j Required minimum 2GB memory.

These are the requirement for neo4j.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-requirements.html

I am currently using neo4j on VMWare.
My VM settings are

```
Memory     - 2GB
Processors - 2
Hard disk  - 20GB
```

It working fine for me.

So update your VM setting and check.

Also check this http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html for Neo4j performance.

Comment: This should solve it. Out of his 1.75 GB, OS will also get certain amount of memory which will leave Insufficient memory for Neo4J